# How to force a plugin to initialize if its div is hidden at load

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this plugin for a Gantt chart, http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt.

I want to be able to have the div class "gantt" hidden when the page loads, and make the div visible by toggle.

I'm finding that when load a page where the gantt div is hidden, the chart doesn't fully render. The div remains as shown here.

```
<div class="gantt"></div>
```

However, when the page is loaded, the chart html is generated.

How can I force the plugin to generate the html if the div is hidden when the page is loaded?

Comment: The issue is likely due to the fact that the hidden element doesn't take up space in the document and for whatever reason the `layout rebuilder` isn't called when toggling the `display`. Instead, use the `visibility` attribute which will ensure the same space is consumed regardless of it's state of `visibility.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ohgodwhy mentioned, you may want to use `visibility` instead of `display`.

```
.selector.hidden {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Two basic fallbacks:

1. try to hide the divs *after* you initialize gantt charts
2. initialize the gantt chart upon toggling it

**Hide after sync**

```
$(".selector").each(function(){
    var hidden = $(this).is(':hidden');
    $(this).show().gantt({
        source: ...
    });
    if (hidden) $(this).hide();
});
```

**Hide upon toggle**

```
function toggleChart(chart) {
    var $chart = $(chart).slideToggle();
    if (!$chart.data('initialized')) {
        $chart.data('initialized', true);
        $chart.gnatt({ /* your options here */ });
    }
}
```